# Reset auto-increment sequence after update for type of data in POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment

I have two existing tables DOS_PROFILE and DOS,

```
CREATE TABLE DOS_PROFILE
(
DOS_PROFILE_ID uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 (),
PAT_ID VARCHAR NOT NULL,
PRODUCT_ID VARCHAR NOT NULL,
REMINDER_TIME VARCHAR,
DOS_SETUP_DATE BIGINT,
TIME_ZONE VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
IS_ACTIVE BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (DOS_PROFILE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE DOS
 (
 DOS_ID uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 (),
 DOS_NUMBER INTEGER,
 DOS_DATE BIGINT NOT NULL,
 DOS_STATUS VARCHAR NOT NULL,
 DOS_PROFILE_ID uuid NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (DOS_ID),
 FOREIGN KEY (DOS_PROFILE_ID) REFERENCES DOS_PROFILE(DOS_PROFILE_ID)
  );
```

**Sample data:**
**DOS**

```
'e5d7b7c2-af76-41b2-80d7-d68bdd4ad596',0,'1483268400000','taken','7e28dc41-2f4b-43d5-9291-3ac147ebbac8'
'62b2e7ff-618a-42c4-a09e-df52dffaeaec',0,'1484478000000','not_logged','7e28dc41-2f4b-43d5-9291-3ac147ebbac8'
'421387af-fbbb-49c6-abd1-a523fec02fbf',0,'1518546600000','taken','d833fcae-d98c-4314-857b-51098075c2da'
'ca6524d5-32f9-4b74-bfaa-a39ce5b92bf1',0,'1518546600000','taken','0e826fc4-09e7-4c83-941e-c9c547fa515f'
'7945c8a5-7d67-4c9d-b67f-065e9282623b',0,'1518546600000','taken','6c15cba5-bbcb-4fba-82d5-a6dbefa3b455'
```

**DOS_PROFILE**

```
'7e28dc41-2f4b-43d5-9291-3ac147ebbac8','1283364','poi','03:30','1516359600000','Pacific/Samoa',false
'd833fcae-d98c-4314-857b-51098075c2da','1283364','poi','18:40','1518546600000','Asia/Kolkata',false
'0e826fc4-09e7-4c83-941e-c9c547fa515f','1283364','poi','18:40','1518546600000','Asia/Kolkata',false
'6c15cba5-bbcb-4fba-82d5-a6dbefa3b455','1283364','poi','18:40','1518546600000','Asia/Kolkata',false
'04c15d61-d6fd-4754-ae65-7af8a1ec667e','1283364','poi','18:40','1518546600000','Asia/Kolkata',false
```

**Sequence I am using for auto increment:**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.dos_dosNumber_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
```

Set DOS_NUMBER for all the existing rows saved in DOS table for PRODUCT_ID='poi' from DOS_PROFILE. The DOS_NUMBER should start from 1 in an incremental order for each PAT_ID;

**What I have tried:**

```
update DOS set dos_number = nextval('dos_dosNumber_seq') where dos_profile_id in 
    (select dos_profile_id from DOS_profile where pat_id = '1283364' and product_id='poi' 
     group by pat_id order by dos_setup_date);
ALTER SEQUENCE dos_dosNumber_seq RESTART WITH 1;
```

In the above approach I need to reset it again and again using a separate query also, I have to explicitly specify the pat_id in the update query. I need a generic update and reset the sequence in the same query.

If a procedure is required, that ll be fine too.
Thanks!

Comment: Why use a sequence? It looks like you should base the numbering on `row_number() over (partition by pat_id order by dos_setup_date)`. You may also introduce a FROM (correlated subquery) clause in your UPDATE.

Comment: Can you give the query, so that I can test it?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I could come up with, there must be some scope for optimization:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.dos_dosNumber_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateDosNumber(i varchar(12)) RETURNS VOID AS $$
    BEGIN        
      update dos set dos_number = nextval('dos_dosNumber_seq') where dos_profile_id in 
    (select dos_profile_id from dos_profile where pat_id = i and product_id='taltz' 
      order by dos_setup_date);
     ALTER SEQUENCE dos_dosNumber_seq RESTART WITH 1;   

    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT updateDosNumber(p.pat_id) from (select distinct pat_id from dos_profile) p ;
```